# How to use intent start front camera?

Tags: android, camera

I tried other questions' methods, but for me, these methods do not work .

I want to use intent to start front camera.
I try to do it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.LENS_FACING_FRONT", 1);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.USE_FRONT_CAMERA", true);
mFile = Utils.getVisitorImage();
Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                getActivity(),
                getActivity().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider",
                mFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

but,it does't work.
my device is Android 7.1.1.
How to use intent start front camera?
I hope someone help me.Thanks.

Comment: @kaihello did you add the permissions?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />

Comment: I tried other methods, but for me, these methods do not work

Comment: @kaihello didnt get you?

Comment: i added permissions, but still not open the front camera.always back camera.

Comment: it's camera problem,i change a phone it's can work.

Comment: @kaihello have you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

To call the **Front camera** you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING", 1);
```

Comment: I added permissions, but still not open the front camera.

Comment: Can you print your LogCat error here?

Comment: I gave the camera permissions, so there is no wrong information

Comment: Sure it will gives some message about your problem @kaihello